# Function passed and invoked in child component doesn't have access to parent state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a parent and a child components.

Parent component has state variable that I want to access.

I pass a function to child component and call it there onClick.

However, the value of the state variable is out of date - not the current value.

```
function Parent(props) {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    function getItems () {
        console.log(items); // always prints "[]" 
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        thirdPartyApiCall().then((fetchedItems) =>
            let newItems = fetchedItems.map(item => <Child id={item.id} getItems={getItems}/>)
            setItems(newItems); // populates items array. "{items}" elements correctly displayed on web page
        );
    }, []);

}


function Child(props) {
    return <button onClick={props.getItems}>{props.id}</button>
}
```

Comment: You can help people help you by making your example **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: I'm not very familiar with hooks yet, but my guess is you need to include `items` in the dependencies array of `useEffect`. (E.g., change `[]` to `[items]`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that causes the infinite loop:(
useEffect called => items updated => useEffect called => ...

Comment: So...my lack of familiarity with hooks bites me. :-) Good luck with it, in any case!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks anyway! Do you think it is react related question? Not just plain javascript scoping?

Comment: Yes, definitely. :-)

Comment: You set your intial state to an empty array - what do you expect it to be when you go to use it then?

Comment: @RandyCasburn inside the useEffect the items array is being populated by Child components after component is mounted. So when I do `console.log(items)` inside the parent component it is not an empty array

Comment: Duh! So you want your items array to contain a list of `<Child>` components. Was completely blind to that...sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes, of course clicking on the button logs `[]`. In this:

```
<Child id={item.id} getItems={getItems}/>
```

`getItem` gets evaluated as a function that logs the items and the items are `[]`, so `[]` is logged. The reason why it doesn't logs the *new* items is because, as your code is being written, React cannot really know when to update the component, because no variable is used in the render phase.

---

This is generally a bad practice to use JSX elements outside of Render because they're not really normal JS variables with predictable behavior. The fact that it compiles is more a *hack* than a *feature*.

Keep vanilla variables in the state, and let the components do the JSX rendering. This approach is *slightly* different than yours, but works as expected, as clicking on either button logs all the items:

```js
const fakeApiCall = () => Promise.resolve([
    {id: 10},
    {id: 20},
    {id: 30},
]);

const Parent = () => {
    const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        fakeApiCall().then(setItems)
    })
    const getItems = () => console.log(items);
    return (
        <div>
            {items.map(item => (
                <Child
                id={item.id}
                key={item.id}
                getItems={getItems}/>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

const Child = ({id, getItems}) => (<button onClick={getItems}>{id}</button>);

window.onload = () => ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, that worked! Thank you so much! I spent 4 hours on this! I didn't realize creating an array of React components could cause this behavior.

Comment: @nino I am facing same issue but here my array rendering in nested component and i am passing array from parent->child->child.will you suggest me how do i fix this issue

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at how javascript [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) works.

Will give a basic idea of what's happening.

`useEffect` would only run once, due to the dependency. So when the child components were rendered `items` was an empty array(`[]`). Your child components would always have this instance of `items` as `useEffect` did not get called with updated `items`.

Hope this helped.

EDIT:1

You might want your parent component to look like this.

```
function Parent(props) {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    function getItems () {
        console.log(items); // always prints "[]" 
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        thirdPartyApiCall().then((fetchedItems) =>
            setItems(newItems);
        );
    }, []);

    return newItems.map(item => <Child key={item.id} id={item.id} getItems={getItems}/>)
}
```

Comment: Yes, that does look right to me! However, I was researching this topic and still could come up with a solution to this problem. Could you please tell what could fix this issue?

Comment: I would suggest not to create the child components inside the useEffect. Just update the items. And render the child components outside, using map. Have updated the original answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!!